# LLVM Pass unsigned long to function

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I want to insert below function
`void threadIsJoining(pthread_t tid) {...}`
like this

```
threadIsJoining(tid) // <-- Hook
pthread_join(tid,NULL)
```

LLVM IR:

```
%0 = load i64, i64* %ptid1, align 8
%call1 = call i32 @pthread_join(i64 %0, i8** null)
```

My attempt:

```
Instruction* i2 = i.getPrevNonDebugInstruction();
LoadInst *li = cast<LoadInst>(i2);
argOperand = li->getOperand(0);
llvm::IRBuilder<> builder(&i);
builder.CreateCall(threadIsJoiningHookFunc,{builder.CreatePointerCast(argOperand,Type::getInt64Ty(M.getContext()), "")});
```

But this is producing code like this:

```
%0 = load i64, i64* %ptid1, align 8
%1 = ptrtoint i64* %ptid1 to i64
call void @_Z12threadJoinedm(i64 %1) // <- should Be %0
%call1 = call i32 @pthread_join(i64 %0, i8** null)
```

The issue is I think with `CreatePointerCast`. So I tried other options like `CreateIntegerCast`, etc. but they are not compiling. What should I change?

Comment: If you want the result of the `load`, then use the `load`. An instruction is its result. If the operand of a load has type foo*, then the load itself has type foo, because it is the result of loading from a pointer to foo, see?

Comment: Thanks a ton. I used `argOperand = li->stripPointerCasts()` and it worked. Slightly off-track, but where do you learn this LLVM stuff as I find their C++ API very hard to use and their official guides are very basic.

Comment: I too found the first month a little challenging. I read other people's code, in particular code in LLVM itself, and after a while things made more sense and life was easier.